# Drawing cards without replacement: all kings before any jacks

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

This is a question that came up with my friends while playing a card drinking game:

You draw cards without replacement from a standard 52-card shuffled deck. What is the probability that you draw *all* of the kings before drawing *any* of the jacks?

I was thinking of a solution along the lines of combinations, but I'm not sure if that's the way to go. Simulation tells me the answer is ~1.4%, but I don't know how to get to this answer.

**Disclaimer:** This is not a homework question. I'm really just curious.

Comment: You should never drink while playing cards.

Answer (score 7):

The only thing that matters is the *relative placement* of the two  critical types of card.

There are $\binom{8}{4}$ equally likely ways to choose the places occupied by the Kings. Only one of these is "favourable."

Thus the probability that all the Kings come before any Jack is $\dfrac{1}{\binom{8}{4}}$. This is approximately $0.0143$, quite close to the number obtained in the simulation.

Comment: Of course, that's so simple. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.